# RDP Certificate subject name though a gateway

Tags: group-policy, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

I have Server 2012 R2 setup with the Hyper-V and Server Essentials role enabled. I am running multiple machines that I would like to RDP to through a RDP Gateway. The gateway is correctly configured and I can "see" the VM's on my network.

I have configured Group Policy on the VM's to use a certificate template (duplicated from the Computer template) called RemoteDesktopAuthentication, that uses the following as the subject name settings:

[image: My certificate subject name setup]

As this is issued through Active Directory it is signed with my Root CA, which is trusted by all clients, and has the following (relevant) properties

```
Subject: CN = TEST-VM, CN = Computers, DC = example, DC = com
Subject Alternative Name: DNS Name=Test-VM.example.com
```

I was hoping that this certificate would allow me to access my VM at TEST-VM and at TEST-VM.example.com but it will only allow me to use TEST-VM.example.com. I know its a minor cosmetic thing having to type the domain after the host name but is there a way to accomplish this task?

Summary: **Can I access my VM's through an RDP gateway using their Machine Name and thier full AD domain name?**

**Edit:** Ryan Bolger has pointed me in the right direction, use the FQDN when a gateway is being used and use a VPN connection to allow access via just the Machine Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the templates don't allow for enough customization of the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) when using auto-enrollment.  In this case, you need another check box for NetBIOS Name (or DNS Short Name).

You basically have two choices.  Keep using auto enrollment and deal with having to type the FQDN (which is good practice anyway).  Or you can manually generate the certificates and specify the additional SAN fields you need like NetBIOS Name (IP address, etc).